# What's the fastest way to find whether a number lies within a list of ranges?

Tags: r, range, apply

i'm really new to R and i've been looking for an easy and fast way to check whether a number lies within a list of ranges. 
for example:

```
Numbers <- c(77,3,66)
RangesList <- data.frame(cbind(c(5,20,33,60,91),c(8,23,45,76,100)))
colnames(RangesList) <- c("Start","End")

> RangesList

  Start End
1     5   8
2    20  23
3    33  45
4    60  76
5    91 100
```

now i'm looking for an easy and fast way (avoiding "if" as much as possible) to check for each number in "Numbers" whether it is inside one of the ranges in RangesList. 
In the above example i would expect the function to result with:
`"FALSE" "FALSE" "TRUE"`
i need to apply this function on 100k rows and my ranges list is around 2000 rows - that's why i'm emphasizing the run-time implications (run-time using "if" takes ~5 min) and i'm looking for a more "elegant" solution.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's way using `sapply` :

```
sapply(Numbers, function(x) any(x >= RangesList$Start & x <= RangesList$End))
#[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

An option by setting key and using non-equi join in `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(RangesList, key=c("Start", "End"))
RangesList[.(v=Numbers), on=.(Start<=v, End>=v), mult="first", by=.EACHI, .N > 0L]$V1
```

timing code:

```
set.seed(0L)
nn <- 100e3
nr <- 2e3
Numbers <- rnorm(nn)
s <- rnorm(nr); e <- rnorm(nr)
RangesList <- data.frame(Start=pmin(s, e), End=pmax(s, e))

library(data.table)
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(times=1L,
    base = abase <- sapply(Numbers, function(x) any(x >= RangesList$Start & x <= RangesList$End)),
    dt = adt <- {
        setDT(RangesList, key=c("Start", "End"))
        RangesList[.(v=Numbers), on=.(Start<=v, End>=v), mult="first", by=.EACHI, .N > 0L]$V1
    }
)
identical(abase, adt)
#[1] TRUE
```

timings:

```
Unit: milliseconds
 expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
 base 2338.6214 2338.6214 2338.6214 2338.6214 2338.6214 2338.6214     1
   dt  804.2691  804.2691  804.2691  804.2691  804.2691  804.2691     1
```